# Docpad alias plugin in the static environment

Tags: docpad

I'm trying to use the alias plugin to do the following:

I have this source structure

```
/src/documents
  gettingstarted.html
  manual.html
```

What I would like in the output is this:

```
/out/
  gettingstarted.html
  manual.html
  index.html -> redirects to gettingstarted.html OR just copies the content of gettingstarted.html
```

I've tried to accomplish this with the alias plugin as follows:

```
alias:
    hard: true
    symlink: true
    aliases: {
        '/index.html': '/gettingstarted.html'
    }
    extensions: [ 'html' ]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything. Does the alias plugin even support the static environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin does support static mode as long as you are using the `hard: true` option (which you are).  Note, this will not *redirect* requests.  Rather, it will create two URLs that have the same contents either by copying the source URL into the target URL or by creating a symlink at the target URL that points to the source URL.

I believe your problem is that you have the source/target mappings backwards. The documentation doesn't make it clear, but the config should follow this pattern:

```
alias:
    aliases: {
        '/source-file-that-exists.html': '/target-file-you-want-to-create.html'
    }
```

So to copy `gettingstarted.html` into `index.html` you'd want:

```
alias:
    hard: true
    symlink: true
    aliases: {
        '/gettingstarted.html': '/index.html'
    }
    extensions: [ 'html' ]
```

Comment: Yep.. I mixed up the source/target. Wasn't too clear from the docs for me apparently. Thanks!